# object-fit: cover with percentages

Tags: html, css

I'm using percentages to scale thumbnails in a gallery on my website, and I can't get `object-fit: cover` to work with them. I'm trying to use `object-fit` so I can get the thumbnails to actually be square instead of whatever aspect ratio the images themselves have.

This is what my code looks like:

```
<div class="gallery">
  <a href="#"><img class="tile" src="#"></a>
</div>
```

(the `a` and `img` tags repeat a bunch of times in each of the `gallery` divs)

And this is my CSS:

```
.gallery {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1400px;
  min-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  font-size: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
}

.gallery img{
  display: inline-block;
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 25%;
}
```

The only `object-fit` that works is `none` which does manage to contain them in the square shape but also doesn't scaled them down at all.

I don't think I can use something other than percentages, because I need the thumbnails to scale down when the `gallery` div itself does.

Comment: can you please make a jsfiddle or snippet here ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/c8se4wbL/

Because the size of the pictrures is dynamic I can't have a set height for them, which causes them to just scale proportionally to the height.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get a square the height should be equal to the width. If you need to use a percentage of a container (`.gallery` in this case) you can do so with the [maintain aspect ratio trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10441480/5157454):

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.gallery {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1400px;
  min-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  font-size: 0;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
}

.gallery a {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 0.2rem;
  margin-bottom: 0.2rem;
  width: calc(25% - 0.2rem);
}

.gallery a::before {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  content: "";
}

.gallery a img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div>
  I'm the content above the gallery
</div>

<div class="gallery">
  <a href="#"><img class="tile" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a1/Mallard2.jpg/1200px-Mallard2.jpg"></a>
  <a href="#"><img class="tile" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/7d/Bliss.png"></a>
  <a href="#"><img class="tile" src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/9/8456/8063950119_57b3cb8818_b.jpg"></a>
  <a href="#"><img class="tile" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/52/Yamaha_Clarinet_YCL-457II-22.tiff/lossy-page1-85px-Yamaha_Clarinet_YCL-457II-22.tiff.jpg"></a>
  <a href="#"><img class="tile" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a1/Mallard2.jpg/1200px-Mallard2.jpg"></a>
  <a href="#"><img class="tile" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/7d/Bliss.png"></a>
  <a href="#"><img class="tile" src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/9/8456/8063950119_57b3cb8818_b.jpg"></a>
  <a href="#"><img class="tile" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/52/Yamaha_Clarinet_YCL-457II-22.tiff/lossy-page1-85px-Yamaha_Clarinet_YCL-457II-22.tiff.jpg"></a>
  <a href="#"><img class="tile" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a1/Mallard2.jpg/1200px-Mallard2.jpg"></a>
  <a href="#"><img class="tile" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/7d/Bliss.png"></a>
  <a href="#"><img class="tile" src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/9/8456/8063950119_57b3cb8818_b.jpg"></a>
  <a href="#"><img class="tile" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/52/Yamaha_Clarinet_YCL-457II-22.tiff/lossy-page1-85px-Yamaha_Clarinet_YCL-457II-22.tiff.jpg"></a>
</div>

<div>
  I'm the content below the gallery
</div>
```

If you need a percentage of the view port width, you can use `vw`:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.gallery {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1400px;
  min-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  font-size: 0;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
}

.gallery img {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 0.2rem;
  margin-bottom: 0.2rem;
  object-fit: cover;
  width: calc(25vw - 0.2rem);
  height: calc(25vw - 0.2rem);
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <a href="#"><img class="tile" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a1/Mallard2.jpg/1200px-Mallard2.jpg"></a>
  <a href="#"><img class="tile" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/7d/Bliss.png"></a>
  <a href="#"><img class="tile" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/23/Hasegawa_Tohaku_-_Pine_Trees_%28Sh%C5%8Drin-zu_by%C5%8Dbu%29_-_right_hand_screen.jpg"></a>
  <a href="#"><img class="tile" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/52/Yamaha_Clarinet_YCL-457II-22.tiff/lossy-page1-85px-Yamaha_Clarinet_YCL-457II-22.tiff.jpg"></a>
</div>
```